# How can I center Bootstrap navbar menu items just for mobile?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I'm using the following navbar. I need to be able to center the menu `li` items when the navbar is collapsed.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="myNav">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto me-4 my-3 my-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link me-lg-3">Menu Item 1</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link me-lg-3">Menu Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The solution I came up with was doing the following:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto me-4 my-3 my-lg-0">     
    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">           
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link me-lg-3">Menu Item 1</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link me-lg-3">Menu Item 2</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

But as mentioned in the comments this is not a valid HTML - to have a div as a child of list element

It does work. But not valid - how can I properly center them then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably just a matter of applying [text alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/text/#text-alignment) selectively for the smaller breakpoint(s).

Note: `d-block` added to the collapse element for demonstration here only. View the full page demo for the alternative layout.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="myNav">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-block">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto me-4 my-3 my-lg-0 text-center">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link me-lg-3">Menu Item 1</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link me-lg-3">Menu Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is working! In fact, I just tried and I did not need `text-lg-start`. I think you used it to view them on start (which is left side) although I already have it on the right side using `ms-auto` (I did not see that `text-lg-start` have any affect, so I removed it - or it does mean to do something?)

Comment: No, that's a mistake or misunderstanding on my part.